# When changing the default timezone with PHP, should one change it back once done?

Tags: php, datetime

Say I want to check if a user logs in within a certain time period (e.g. to disallow logins during some period), but I want to do so relative to my timezone.

I would do something like the following:

```
        $time = ...; // Get the start and end times for our application logic

        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $currTime = new DateTime();
        $startTime = new DateTime($time['StartTime']);
        $endTime = new DateTime($time['EndTime']);

        if($currTime > $startTime && $currTime < $endTime) { ... }
```

Should we reset the `default_timezone` (by `get`-ing it first and then setting it to that again)? Does the above only work for the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to set it back again, its set at run time and is only within the scope of the calling script.

Per your comment reply.

Try adding a file (php.ini) into your hosting account folder it should be just outside your webroot, user in the example below.

Add this line to it.

date.timezone = "America/New_York"

/home/user/public_html/

One of two things will happen, either it wont work, nothing ventured nothing gained, or hopefully, it will set the timezone for you account wide and save you dealing with timezones in your script unless you explicitly need to on a use case basis.

Comment: I see. Could you also explain how one would set the timezone globally, in that case (i.e. make it so that our application is always doing things relative to our chosen timezone)?

Comment: yes, you can set it in a configuration file as they are normally called up by every page. For instance if you have your database details included from such a file you could add your timezone setting in there instead.

The prefered method of course would be to set the time zone in php.ini for the server, or inside an account specific php.ini if your host has the server setup to look for them.